# Sum arrays' columns in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sum

I am pretty new to AngularJS (and to development in general). I am trying to create a simple game and I am stuck with one problem.

The user can add words to a list and my script automatically associate 5 random numbers (in a specific range) to every item with the following:

```
$scope.randomNum = getNum();
function getNum () {
    var arr = [];
    min = 1;
    max = 5;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + minEffort);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I would like to dynamically get the sums of the columns of those arrays. For instance, if the user adds three words:

- First
- Second
- Third

and these words get respectively the following random numbers:

- [0,5,2,4,2]
- [3,5,1,2,1]
- [4,3,4,1,2]

I need to push to the page the total of every column: 7, 13, 7, 7, 5. And I also need to use those totals to run further math.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**
I stumbled upon this filter:

```
app.filter('sumByKey', function () {
  return function (data, key) {
    if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
      return 0;
    }

    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      sum += parseInt(data[i][key]);
    }

    return sum;
  };
});
```

That allows me to get the sum for a single columns with

```
{{items|sumByKey: 'randomNum[i]'}}
```

Can I reiterate it automatically for the total number of columns? Can I store the results in another array for further operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope.sums will contain sum of all collumns. You can use it further.

```
$scope.words = [];
$scope.sums = [];
$scope.getNum = function () {
    var arr = [];
    min = 1;
    max = 5;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + minEffort);
    }
    return arr;
};

//add word and associate random number arrays
$scope.add_word = function (word) {
    $scope.words.push({word_text: word, numbers: $scope.getNum()});
};

//give colums sums,no matter what how many rows are
$scope.get_colums_sum = function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.words, function (word, key) {
        angular.forEach(word.numbers, function (number, key) {
            if (isNaN($scope.sums[key])) {
                $scope.sums[key] = number;
            } else {
                $scope.sums[key] = $scope.sums[key] + number;
            }
        });
    });
    console.log($scope.sums);
};

$scope.add_word('first word');
$scope.add_word('second word');
$scope.add_word('third word');
$scope.get_colums_sum();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mudasser. I am not sure why I am getting "undefined" for get_colums_sum()...
I put my code in JSFiddle, but apparently it is not working at all: https://jsfiddle.net/nitecorp/n61cmkfg/2/

While on my local server everything but the sum is working...

Comment: @MirkoG. you were missing to define $scope.sums in controller,which was being used in get_col_sum function. Here is plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/fDgY0syOUacSXtJVBQlr?p=preview , $scope.sums is array which keeps total of all columns.

Comment: Thanks Mudasser, If I return the sum something weird happens: the first sum looks like the number of the first array are repeated twice, then the sum changes as soon as I type something in the input text field: http://plnkr.co/edit/ltNwhJupqfWINHc8cl1N?p=preview :(

Comment: @MirkoG. check now http://plnkr.co/edit/A7RCdXMUst2pZF8cN6K2?p=preview  its working right, i was not making $scope.sums = [] before each new sums cycle.It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every array has the same length (5 elements in this case) you can apply the next algorithm.

`array_of_arrays` will be an array of the arrays to sum, it means:

```
var array_to_arrays = [[0,5,2,4,2], [3,5,1,2,1], [4,3,4,1,2]];

function sumCols(array_to_arrays) {
   var sum = 0;
   var sum_cols = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for(var j = 0; j < array_to_arrays.length; j++) {
         sum += array_to_arrays[j][i];
      }
      sum_cols.push(sum);
      sum = 0;
   }
   return sum_cols;
}
```

I created a plnkr with a example: http://plnkr.co/edit/0FElcQamh9b7nHbQDMkn?p=preview

Comment: Thank you Fran, how can I make this solution independent from the number of arrays? array_to_array could contain from 0 to N arrays. How do I dynamically get it?

Comment: The function is independent of ````array_to_arrays```` length. The only assumption is that every component must be equal length (five in this case).